# Sequence whose ratio satisfies a certain condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am interested in constructing a positive sequences $(a_n)_{n \in I}$, where $I=\mathbb{N}_0$ or $I = \mathbb{Z}$, such that
$$
\sup_{ n \in I } \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} < \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \sup_{ n \in I } \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \infty.
$$
We can take $a_n = 2^{n^2}$. Then
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}, \quad \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = 2^{2n-1}.
$$
The required conditions are satisfied for $I = \mathbb{N}_0$ but not for $I=\mathbb{Z}$. What can be done in the latter case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $2^{-(n^2)}$ when $n \lt 0$?  Then, for $n \lt 0, \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}=2^{2n+1}, \frac {a_n}{a_{n-1}}=2^{-2n+1}$

Comment: But the first ratio is unbounded for $n>0$ (the supremum is taken over $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I was suggesting my form just for negative $n$, using yours for positive $n$

Comment: I see now, thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the sequence for $n>0$ in a way that makes it summable, as is the case for $n<0$?

Comment: I don't think so.  Your conditions mean the positive sequence has to blow up.